# How to make <li> scrolling like parallax?

Tags: html, parallax

What is the best way to make 'li' tags also scroll like parallax?

```
<div class="wrapper bg-4">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-7 invest">
                    <h3>Invest in Azerbaijan</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Total Area:  86,600 km2</li>
                        <li>Water (%): 1.6</li>
                        <li>GDP   (PPP):   $168.4 billion</li>
                        <li>Time zone:   AZT (UTC+04)</li>
                        <li>Population:   9,754,830</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-5 flames">
                    <img src="img/flames.svg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

First put this:

```
.parallax { 
    background-image: *image URL*;

    height: 100%; 

    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

And then put your div down at HTML but make sure you added this code before and after the div

```
<div class="parallax"></div>
```

Should look like:

```
<div class="parallax"></div>

<div>
  Whatever
</div>

<div class="parallax"></div>
```

Comment: ok, but then text in 'li' tags is not scrolling like parallax, only background has this effect